# Cannot query ManagedContent from Apex

Tags: apex

If I run this query:

`[SELECT ContentKey FROM ManagedContent WHERE Id = 'Id']`

in dev console I get back the content key no problem

When I run the same query from an aura enabled apex method it returns nothing. The class has without sharing.

```
List<ManagedContent> contentKeys = [SELECT ContentKey FROM ManagedContent WHERE Id = 'Same Id'];

System.debug('DEBUG: ' + contentKeys.size()); //returns 0
```

The running user (same user in both scenarios) has a System Admin Profile. It seems I cannot update the object level permissions of ManagedContent.

Any ideas?

Comment: does the aura class have version V59?

Comment: I've also been experiencing this. I can query and get the results back in the query editor and execute anonymous window. But whenever I want to reference the results in my LWC, it returns nothing. Even in the logs (dev console), it says there are no rows (no results). Has anyone came up with a solution?

Comment: Perhaps you could call the REST API from Apex to get to it?